# if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'): break cap.release() cv2.destroyAllWindows() crashes

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, artificial-intelligence, face-id

Everytime I run the following code on jupyter notebook the macbook camera works well but when i press "q" to quit it freezes and crashes

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    cv2.imshow("Image Collection", frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
        
#Release the webcam
cap.release()
#Close the image show frame
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any advice? Thank you very much!!

Python: 3.9

I tried to intent it better and to change it using other ways but I still got the same problem